# Deserialize to list

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

i am using the `XmlSerializer.Serialize` and `XmlSerializer.Deserialize` 
i have a class MetricResult:

```
public   class Metricresult
{
        public string metric;
        public string newvalue;
        public string deltavalue;

}
```

and i am calculating some results that will be stored in :

```
List<Metricresult> metricresults = new List<Metricresult>();
```

i changed this list to xml file succefully and in an other project i need to deserialize this list but there is an exception thrown :

```
there-is-an-error-in-xml-document-0-0-during-deserialization
```

---

the xml File

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfMetricresult xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Metricresult>
    <metric>numberofdeclaration</metric>
    <newvalue>0</newvalue>
    <deltavalue>0</deltavalue>
  </Metricresult>
  <Metricresult>
    <metric>numberofdeclaration</metric>
    <newvalue>0</newvalue>
    <deltavalue>0</deltavalue>
  </Metricresult>
  <Metricresult>
    <metric>numberofdeclaration</metric>
    <newvalue>0</newvalue>
    <deltavalue>0</deltavalue>
  </Metricresult>
  <Metricresult>
    <metric>numberofdeclaration</metric>
    <newvalue>0</newvalue>
    <deltavalue>0</deltavalue>
  </Metricresult>
  <Metricresult>
    <metric>numberofdeclaration</metric>
    <newvalue>0</newvalue>
    <deltavalue>0</deltavalue>
  </Metricresult>
  <Metricresult>
    <metric>numberofdeclaration</metric>
    <newvalue>0</newvalue>
    <deltavalue>0</deltavalue>
  </Metricresult>
</ArrayOfMetricresult>
```

Comment: Can you post the exact contents of the XML file?

Comment: Show your serialization/deserialization code

Comment: Yes, serialized data looks right so... must be an error in your deserialization code.

Comment: i did some changes and i have this problem now {"<ArrayOfMetricresult Xmlns=''> was not expected."}  (2, 2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Weird, coz the following works perfectly fine for me:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class MetricResult
{
    public string Metric { get; set; }
    public string NewValue { get; set; }
    public string DeltaValue { get; set; }

}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // define some metric results to serialize
        var metricResults = new[] 
        { 
            new MetricResult { Metric = "metric 1", NewValue = "new value 1", DeltaValue = "delta 1" },
            new MetricResult { Metric = "metric 2", NewValue = "new value 2", DeltaValue = "delta 2" },
            new MetricResult { Metric = "metric 3", NewValue = "new value 3", DeltaValue = "delta 3" },
        }.ToList();
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(metricResults.GetType());

        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create("metrics.xml"))
        {
            // serialize the metric results we defined previously to metrics.xml
            serializer.Serialize(writer, metricResults);
        }

        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("metrics.xml"))
        {
            // read metrics.xml and deserialize back
            metricResults = (List<MetricResult>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            foreach (var result in metricResults)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("metric: {0}, new value: {1}, delta: {2}", result.Metric, result.NewValue, result.DeltaValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and `metrics.xml` looks as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfMetricResult xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <MetricResult>
    <Metric>metric 1</Metric>
    <NewValue>new value 1</NewValue>
    <DeltaValue>delta 1</DeltaValue>
  </MetricResult>
  <MetricResult>
    <Metric>metric 2</Metric>
    <NewValue>new value 2</NewValue>
    <DeltaValue>delta 2</DeltaValue>
  </MetricResult>
  <MetricResult>
    <Metric>metric 3</Metric>
    <NewValue>new value 3</NewValue>
    <DeltaValue>delta 3</DeltaValue>
  </MetricResult>
</ArrayOfMetricResult>
```

Comment: heh; it isn't just me that can't ignore a `public string newvalue;`, then? ;p Although to keep the original data layout (mainly a note for the OP, not Darin), you would need to add `[XmlElement("newvalue")]` before the property.

Comment: @Ammaedragas can we ask what was broken in your code? Since that may help the next reader who finds it on google, etc?

Comment: first mistake : i did not use the XmlReader and the second was in the Deserializiation code thank you

Comment: because if we use something else than the xmlreader  the exception of 'there-is-an-error-in-xml-document-0-0-during-deserialization' will be thrown

Answer (score 1):

An error at 0,0 usually means you have whitespace at the start of your xml file, before the first element. Look carefully at the xml (perhaps looking at the binary, rather than the text - it could also be a unicode invisible space, etc).

Also: whenever using `XmlSerializer`, look at the `InnerException`s:

```
catch(Exception ex) {
    while(ex != null) {
        Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        ex = ex.InnerException;
    }
}
```

there are usually very detailed explanations, if you look all the way through the messages.

One very common error people make is when using streams, *not rewinding them*. The following will error with a 0,0 error:

```
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        serializer.Serialize(ms, metricResults);
        serializer.Deserialize(ms);
    }
```

because the serialize left the stream at the end. If you have code like this, reset the stream to the start (`ms.Position = 0;`) between serialize and deserialize. See also: [How many ways can you mess up IO?](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com.br/2013/02/how-many-ways-can-you-mess-up-io.html)

Comment: Could be a BOM at the start maybe?

Comment: @MatthewWatson maybe, but *most* of the time a BOM will be handled correctly. The only way to know is to see both the deserialization code and the *binary* of the data